# Unable to dispatch touch to JS as the catalyst instance has not been attached

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using [react-native-share-extension](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension) for sharing images from gallery.
So I use two activities(MainActivity and ShareActivity).

But when ShareActivity is finished, there is no reaction from the main app.
All UI components are stopped.

Android monitor message says 
"Unable to dispatch touch to JS as the catalyst instance has not been attached"

My code is below.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:name=".share.MyShareActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_share"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="standard"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Share.Transparent" >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

MyShareActivity.java

```
package com.mobileopenalm.share;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.github.alinz.reactNativeShareExtension.ShareExActivity;
import com.mobileopenalm.BuildConfig;


public class MyShareActivity extends ReactActivity {
    static MyShareActivity myActivity = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myActivity = this;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "MyShareEx";
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    static protected MyShareActivity getActivity(){
        return myActivity;
    }
}
```

InternalShare.java(declare reactMethod)

```
public class InternalShare extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
        public InternalShare(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
            super(reactContext);
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "ShareExtension";
        }

        @ReactMethod
        public void close() {
            MyShareActivity.getActivity().finish();
        }

        @ReactMethod
        public void data(Callback successCallback){
//            WritableMap map = Arguments.createMap();

            Intent intent = getCurrentActivity().getIntent();
            String action = intent.getAction();
            String type = intent.getType();
            String[] value = null;

            if (type == null) {
                type = "";
            }

            //if you want to support more, just add more things here.
            //at the moment we are only supporting browser URL
            if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)) {

                ClipData c = intent.getClipData();
                int count = c.getItemCount();
                value  = new String[count];
                for(int i = 0; i < count ; i++){
                    value[i] = c.getItemAt(i).getUri().toString();
                }
            }

            if(value == null){
                successCallback.invoke("");
            } else {
                successCallback.invoke(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

share.android.js - close method (Share extension starts here.)

```
onClose() {
    // console.log(NativeModules.ShareExtension.data())
    NativeModules.ShareExtension.close();

  },
```

index.android.js

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
 import Share from './share.android';

 'use strict';

 var { AppRegistry } = require('react-native');
 var App = require('./App/App');
 // var DropDownApp = require('./App/DropDown');


AppRegistry.registerComponent('mobileOpenAlm', () => App);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyShareEx', () => Share);
```

Details -

When I share photos from gallery, app redirected share.android.js.
And main app(mobileOpenAlm) go to background.

After using onClose() method at share.android.js, app closed successfully. But I went back to main app, app has not responding.

And log is below.

Unable to dispatch touch to JS as the catalyst instance has not been attached.

How can I fix this problem?